# Query between dates not working on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying this query and is it not returning elements:

```
Requerimiento.where(fecha_hora: 30.day.ago.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

> Requerimiento Load (52.9ms)  SELECT  "requerimientos".* FROM
> "requerimientos" WHERE "requerimientos"."fecha_hora" BETWEEN $1 AND $2
> LIMIT $3  [["fecha_hora", "2022-10-10 23:00:00"], ["fecha_hora",
> "2022-11-10 23:59:59.999999"], ["LIMIT", 11]]

It should find any of this rows:
[image]

When I execute this sql directly from a sql client:

```
SELECT  "requerimientos".* FROM "requerimientos" WHERE vendedor = 'rm05' AND fecha_hora BETWEEN "2022-10-10 23:00:00" AND "2022-11-10 23:59:59.999999"
```

I got this error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "2022-10-10 23:00:00" does not exist
```

Comment: I have the same query in another proyect using Rails 7 and it works find; could it be a bug?

Comment: There you got the image with the data in the table

Comment: the query generated and empty array... as you can see in this ticket

Comment: Yes, because all db call are working.. even that one, were when you remove the where using the dates... check my last update

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for strings, double quotes are for identifiers (such as column and table names). You'd want to use `SELECT  "requerimientos".* FROM "requerimientos" WHERE vendedor = 'rm05' AND fecha_hora BETWEEN '2022-10-10 23:00:00' AND '2022-11-10 23:59:59.999999'`

Comment: OK, that is the issue; confirmed there is a bug in the rails api query; that fixed the issue